# List identical words and their numbers of occurrence in text file

Tags: bash, command-line

For example

I have a text file `animal.txt` which contains:

```
bird
bird
dog
rabbit
dog
cat
rabbit
dog
bird
cat
bird
bird
enter code here
```

I would like to have some script which can give me this result:

```
$ ./program.sh animals.txt
bird 5
cat 2
dog 3
rabbit 2
```

Note: the result does not need to be in this format.

I think it's not difficult to write some straightforward program to read the words into an array then count their numbers of occurrence manually but I'm here to ask you for some more "quick and dirty" approach on this problem.

---

Thank you to all answerers. For me, the **best solution** is here:

```
cat animals.txt | sort | uniq -c –
```

from `@cnicutar`.

Comment: `cat animals.txt | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @cnicutar Would be nice if you could create an answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple ***uniq*** + ***sort*** + ***awk*** pipeline:

```
uniq -c <(sort animal.txt) | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

The output:

```
bird 5
cat 2
dog 3
rabbit 2
```

---

I would also recommend you another great tool called GNU [***datamash***](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -s -g1 count 1 <animal.txt
```

The output (tab `\t` separated):

```
bird    5
cat 2
dog 3
rabbit  2
```

Answer (score 1):

try following too in awk.

**Solution 1st:** If you need output same as Input_file's order then following may help.

```
awk '!a[$1]{b[++i]=$1} {a[$1]++} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print b[j],a[b[j]]}}'  Input_file
```

**Solution 2nd:** If you don't bother about their output order then following may help you.

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'   Input_file
```